# How to delete items containing specific string matching in DynamoDB table?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I want to delete specific string matching items in the table. For example, `Table1` is having `Foo123Bar` and `Foo345Bar` in the `name` column.

I want to delete two recs in `name` column.

Comment: Can you provide what is the primary key and sort key in your table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solve it,

You need to scan the table with the conditions and delete them with a batch delete or delete item.

**Scan and Query Example:**

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/dynamodb-example-query-scan.html

**Batch Delete Example:**

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#batchWriteItem-property

Answer (score 0):

Based on whether the **name** column is primary key, sort key or an attribute, you can use different approaches to delete the item.

If the **name** column is a primary key, you can directly delete multiple items using [BatchWriteItem](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html). If you use [DynamoDB Document Client](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html), you can use the `batchWrite` [method](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#batchWrite-property) to delete multiple items in the table as shown below.

```
var params = {
  RequestItems: {
    'Table1': [
      {
        DeleteRequest: {
          Key: { name: 'Foo123Bar' }
        }
      },
      {
        DeleteRequest: {
          Key: { name: 'Foo345Bar' }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};

var documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

documentClient.batchWrite(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  else console.log(data);
});
```

If the **name** column is not a private key but a sort key or queryable  key in an index, you need to query and **delete** the items by finding their primary key and sort key one by one using `deleteItem` [method](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteItem.html).

If the name column is a normal attribute, you need to **scan** and **delete** instead of query.

Using [DynamoDB Document Client](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html) you can call the [scan](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#scan-property) or [query](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#query-property) with required parameters easily.

Comment: Thank you Ashan, but the name is not a key, I just want to delete the only item value, The above one is deleting the entire record. how to specify where condition please help on this

Comment: Then you need to scan and conditionally match the name to find the record, after finding it, you can use the key to delete it. Or else you can create a global secondary index to quickly find the item and its key to delete.